# How to get an enum of static class members in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have a Java class (which I do not control and cannot modify) which has a large number of static String members. How can I have these as an enum (for convenience in coding)?

E.g. I have:

```java
public class ClassWithStaticMembers {
  public static String ONE = "one";
  public static String TWO = "dos";
}
```

...and I want to derive the following from it:

```java
public enum NUMBERS {
  ONE,
  TWO
}
```

Is this possible, with reflection or otherwise?

(Assume I don't know Java well, and that I have 100+ values, so repeating each is painful and not desirable (in case more values get added later). Also I don't need the actual values from the class ("one" and "dos" above)).

Comment: 1. it makes no sense. 2. `Numbers.valueOf(ClassWithStaticMembers.ONE.toUpperCase());`

Comment: What convenience of coding, exactly? Just using the constant name is pretty much the same if it's a static final or if it's an enum constant. The question is if there are any other attributes of enum which you consider important.

Comment: Convenience, possibly mixed with Java ignorance and laziness, is that I have a context where an enum is used (like the one above, but with more than 100 values), and I've found a class which has the same values as static members. I'm either too lazy, scared or not allowed to change either context, so I want a function to map between them (of form Class -> Enum or otherwise). I don't want to duplicate values (so that I benefit from future updates of the class, for example, in the enum-using contexts).

Comment: " If you simply want to parse these strings into constants of an existing enum, then it doesn't require usage of refection": possible I this is what I want: how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple: Enum are statically described so there isn't any possibility to create it by reflection.

You can still create an enumeration that wraps your constants, and optionally had a unit test (that uses reflection) to ensure that your enum is complete.

```
public enum NumbersEnumeration {
  ONE(ClassWithStaticMembers.ONE),
  TWO(ClassWithStaticMembers.TWO);
  private static final String name;
  public String getName(){return name};
  public NumbersEnumeration(String name){this.name=name;}
}


public class NumbersEnumerationTest{

  @Test
  public void checkEnumComplete() throws Exception{
    var fields = List.of(ClassWithStaticMembers.class.getDeclaredFields());
    for( var field:fields){
      Assertions.assertNotNull(NumbersEnumeration.valueof(field.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

(there may be compilation problems on reflection but you got the idea)

Comment: ...Thanks. I suppose my thinking was that the class is statically described too, so it ought to be possible to map from one statically described thing to another....

Comment: @phhu Yes enum is a particular case of class, no polymorphism for example, so no magic, one have to adapt to it. I slightly change my answer because you have to loo on one class and check the other one

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain `java.lang.reflect.Field` instances representing fields defined by your class using `Class.getDeclaredFields()` and filter out those that marked as `static` and access their values.

**But** the problem is that `getDeclaredFields()` does **not guarantee** that an array it returns would be ordered in any particular way. Here's a quote from the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()):

> The elements in the returned array are **not sorted** and are **not in any particular order**.

So if you were thinking about associating static fields and enum members automatically based on their order of declaration, then it wouldn't work, Reflection API can't help here.

I would advise introducing a separate utility-class which would wrap a `Map` associating string values and enum constants.

```
public class NumbersUtils {
    public static final Map<String, Numbers> NUMBERS = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry("one", Numbers.ONE),
        Map.entry("dos", Numbers.TWO),
        ...
    );
    
    private NumbersUtils() {} // utility classes are not meant to be instantiated

    public static Numbers toNumber(String str) {
        if (!NUMBERS.containsKey(str)) throw new IllegalStateException(); // or remove this line if you don's want to throw in such case, method would return null instead
        
        return NUMBERS.get(str);
    }
}
```

Even if you have a possibility of modifying the enum, probably it would be better to keep this logic outside the enum and within the enum you can introduce a method delegating to `NumbersUtils.toNumber()`

#### Sidenotes:

- If these static strings and enums in your code represent the same thing in different languages, and they are mean to facilitate internationalization of the application, then keeping hard-coded strings you might want to get familiar with the proper I18N technics (through `properties` files and `ResourceBundle`s). [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html) will give a general idea on that topic.
- Try to adhere to the [Java language naming conventions][conventions] while writing code. Names enums (as well as classes and interfaces) should newer be written in uppercase.